# Converting 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian' to a float while using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, netcdf4

I am working with netcdf4 package while analyzing climate data from CRU. I was able to get a time series plot for monthly temp. variation in city of Kabul from 2011 thru 2019.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(time,global_average)
ax.set_xlabel('Time(in days since Jan 1,1901)')
ax.set_ylabel('Monthly Temperature')
ax.set_title('Variation of Monthly Temperature in Kabul City')
plt.show()
```

Here the `time` variable is number of days since `Jan 1,1900`.

[image]

But I am trying to add the time axis as values like ' 01-01-2011', 02-01-2012' and so on. I tried to convert the time dimension into `cftime.DatetimeGregorian` using the following function;

```
t = netCDF4.num2date(temp_data_2011_2019.variables['time'][:],temp_data_2011_2019.variables['time'].units,\
                     temp_data_2011_2019.variables['time'].calendar)
```

This works and gives me a masked array. But when  put this argument `np.ma.getdata(t)`  in the plot command,  get the error

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeGregorian'

can use an alternative way to get the dates in desired format in the line plot?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know cftime, but why not use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to do your conversion?

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['Jan 1, 1900', 'Aug 8, 2021']})
```

```
          date
0  Jan 1, 1900
1  Aug 8, 2021
```

conversion:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d, %Y')
```

output:

```
0   1900-01-01
1   2021-08-08
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And if you want to get strings with the DD-MM-YYYY format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d, %Y').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

output:

```
0    01-01-1900
1    08-08-2021
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Appreciate your. response. But I am working with a netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset, not a data frame. If there are ways to convert this structure to a data frame, kindly let me know. It will be really helpful.